# Best way to connect PHP script to executable on localhost

Tags: php, c++, sockets, localhost, pipe

I am creating a C++ app which must provide information to a PHP script running on the same box.  I'm wondering what is the best way to connect the app with the PHP script?

I could create a simple HTTP server in C++, or I could create a tcp socket and listen for a connection (not sure what php offers for access to localhost ports), create a local domain socket, etc..

ideas?

---

The C++ program is a service that is constantly running, so I'm not sure exec from php makes sense.  Unless you are suggesting I write a second executable that communicates with the services, and sends back results through stdout?

Also sounds like a lot of overhead to use exec

Comment: What about simple IPC methods as pipes?

Comment: Can I access IPC from my php script?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [exec](http://php.net/function.exec) command.